# Enqueue js in wordpress with charset

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have script

```
<script src="js/app/script.js" charset="iso-8859-1"></script>
```

I need to enqueue this js in wordpress with charset.  How can I do it ?

I tried do it like that

```
    private static function includeScriptWithCharset($path, $charset){
        //  I need      charset="iso-8859-1"
        wp_enqueue_script ($path, plugins_url($path). " ". $charset);
    }
```

Comment: Here is a really good answer. Best to check on the Stack Excange WordPress Site in future. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110929/adding-additional-attributes-in-script-tag-for-3rd-party-js

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old now, however I have the answer for this, in case this still helps Serg, or helps anyone else who comes across this issue.

The way to do this is to use the WordPress 'script_loader_tag' hook as follows:

```js
// First enqueue your scripts as follows:

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/some.js', array( 'jquery' ), '6.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-other-handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/someother.js', array( 'jquery' ), '6.0');
```

```js
// Next use the script loader hook as follows:

function my_async_scripts( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    // the handles of the enqueued scripts we want to async
    $async_scripts = array( 'my-script-handle', 'my-other-handle' );

    if ( in_array( $handle, $async_scripts ) ) {
        return '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $src . '" charset="iso-8859-1"></script>' . "\n";
    }

    return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'my_async_scripts', 10, 3 );
```